# Why is my application with AutoCompleteTextView crashing down

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I am trying to learn AutoCompleteTextView in android. I made a small app with AutoCompleteTextView against a few names. The app has no syntax errors. But, when I upload it to the emulator for testing, it crashes down at the start screen itself.
Please help.

```
package com.mavenmaverick.autocomplete_test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[] presidents= { "John F. Kennedy",
                    "Lyndon B. Johnson",
                    "Richard Nixon",
                    "Gerald Ford",
                    "Jimmy Carter",
                    "Ronald Reagan",
                    "George H. W. Bush",
                    "Bill Clinton",
                    "George W. Bush",
                    "Barack Obama"
                    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.names,presidents);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

    textView.setThreshold(3);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}





<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/names"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/names"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: LogCat]

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change-

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.names);
```

Into-

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
```

Also change-

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.names, presidents);
```

Into-

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, presidents);
```

Comment: I have changed it. Now the app starts. But, when I enter 3 alphabets as textView.setThreshold(3); the app crashes.

Comment: You are using text view id as parameter in your ArrayAdapter. that is wrong.

Comment: android provide some inbuilt layouts to use like android.R.layout.select_dialog_item.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Can I ask one another thing please ?

Comment: See, when I enter something, I get an autocomplete prediction. Like when I enter "Joh", I get "John F. Kennedy". Now, if the user clicks on "John F. Kennedy", it takes him into an activity that gives him info about John F. Kennedy. What should I do to get this ? How do I make the autocomplete prediction clickable ?

Comment: I dont know how to do this. Post new question related to this. Its seem good idea. I also learn how to do this.

Comment: I have one idea you have to create one button below. And on click pass name to other activity and in other activity use this name to compare with switch statements and show statements if some case true.

Comment: Okay. I will try this. But, first I am posting a new question.

Comment: My new question is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877325/how-do-i-make-the-autocomplete-prediction-clickable

Comment: Okay :) How to pass the 'prediction' to other activity ? I am trying to implement your suggestion.

Comment: See on your question I posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.names,presidents);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
```

to

```
  AutoCompleteTextView textView=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    textView.setThreshold(1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,presidents);
                textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this will work

Comment: I did, but it crashes when I enter the first alphabet itself.

Comment: Post your logcat and xml file.

Comment: Updated logcat and XML.

Comment: say.If I can.I will surely help.

Comment: See, when I enter something, I get an autocomplete prediction. Like when I enter "Joh", I get "John F. Kennedy". Now, if the user clicks on "John F. Kennedy", it takes him into an activity that gives him info about John F. Kennedy. What should I do to get this ? How do I make the autocomplete prediction clickable ?

Comment: you can implement addtextchangedlistener to achieve that http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html or you can use a button on the right hand side of your autocompletetextview,clicking on which it will take you to the desired page.

Answer (score 0):

Here must check

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.names);
```

that `names` is the id of your `AutoCompleteTextView` in your `activity_main.xml` file.

Because your logcat clearly says that you have a `ClassCast Exception`. So must check the id in your `activity_main.xml`file.

So change here from

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.names);
```

to

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.names,presidents);
```

You need to apply your `Threshold` to 1 instead of 3 because

```
When threshold is less than or equals 0, a threshold of 1 is applied.
```

**UPDATE:**

You have to change this from

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.names,presidents);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String>p = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivityName.this, R.layout.customlayout, R.id.names, presidents);
```

Where `customlayout` is the layout in which your `TextView` will be which id is `names`.

Comment: id of the AutoCompleteTextView is 'autoCompleteTextView1' & id of textView is 'names'

Comment: I have changed it. Now the app starts. But, when I enter 3 alphabets as textView.setThreshold(3); the app crashes.

Comment: I changed it to 1 and now the app crashes as soon as I enter the first alphabet.

Comment: Yes. But, I couldn't get your custom layout thing.

Comment: So where is your TextView in which xml file??